# "/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named google-oauthlib-tool" When trying to install Google Assistant on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine

I have installed the entire Google Assistant suite on Mac OS X (El Capitan) and eveyr time I try to do this command:

google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/... --save --headless

It gives me: "/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named google-oauthlib-tool"

It's as if I'm not calling this tool from the right directory?

This is the original article: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine/

Comment: Do you have the Google Assistant SDK installed? If so is it installed in a virtual env?